# Strange ls behaviour

Tags: command-line, ls, fish

When I type `ls` in home directory it shows names of directories with suffix `/` :
`Desktop/ examples.desktop Jupyter notebook/ peda/ Public/` and so on. So how can I fix it?

**EDIT:**

I use fish shell, `type ls`:

```
ls is a function with definition
function ls --description 'List contents of directory'
    set -l param --color=auto
    if isatty 1
        set param $param --indicator-style=classify
    end
    command ls $param $argv
end
```

Comment: You probably have `ls` aliased to either `ls -F` or `ls -p`

Comment: ^ What steeldriver said. Run `type ls` to find out.

Comment: @wjandrea edited!

Comment: @steeldriver may be I should find this alias in config of fish?

Comment: @Tehada I don't use Fish, but `--indicator-style=classify` is the relevant bit for sure.

Comment: @Tehada I don't use `fish` either so I can't say where that would be configured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a system function installed from the `fish-common` package in `/usr/share/functions/ls.fish`.

I can see three options for disabling the system function:

1. Delete `/usr/share/functions/ls.fish`.  (**Not recommended.**)  It will probably be recreated whenever the `fish-common` package is updated.
2. Disable it once by running **`functions --erase ls`**.  Disable it automatically when your shell is initialized by adding that to your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file.  (`--erase` can be abbreviated `-e`.)
3. Override it locally, by creating your own function of the same name.  Just type in a new function with the same name and your own preferences.  The `funcsave` command afterward saves the function in `~/.config/fish/functions/ls.fish`.  (Note this example changes the description string and the parameter added in the *if* block):

   ```
   user@host ~> function ls --description 'List directory (local override)'
                   set -l param --color=auto
                   if isatty 1
                       set param $param --quoting-style=literal
                   end
                   command ls $param $argv
                end

   user@host ~> funcsave ls
   ```

I'm fairly new to `fish`, so there may be other ways to do what you want.